# OSX brew executable owned by root?

Tags: macos, homebrew

Should `/usr/local/bin/brew` be owned by `root:admin` or `$USER:admin`?

---

**Background**: `brew update` is failing.

```
$ brew update 
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
Error: Failed to update tap: homebrew/dupes
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
Error: Failed to update tap: homebrew/versions
Already up-to-date.
```

I've followed both https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/10292 and https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/9953. My `/usr/local/.git` and `/usr/local/Cellar` have $USER:admin permissions.

However, I found out that the brew executable in `/usr/local/brew` belongs to `root:admin`. It makes sense to me that it would be `$USER:admin` instead, but since I don't remember setting it like that I don't want to change it and mess something up.

Comment: probably root, and you should be doing `sudo brew update` instead.

Comment: @MarcB brew don't like sudo, it'll politely decline the offer

Comment: @MarcB `brew` is supposed to work without root; it is the recommended way of using it.

Comment: well, then you'd be running brew under your ID, no matter what its file ownership is (unless it's suid/sgid).

Comment: For posterity, changing the id to mine made no difference, I was having the same errors. (Don't remember but the group probably had x set.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$USER:admin`. Everything should be owned by your user account. Something like `chown -R $USER Library/Homebrew` should help (the taps have their git repos under Library/Taps).

If you'd like to use Homebrew in a multi-user setup, consider [Brewdo](https://github.com/zigg/brewdo).

Comment: I was still have some permission errors so I uninstalled it using https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223 and did a fresh installation. It's working fine now.